# Где хранить общие для всех приложений теги шаблонов?

Tags: python, веб-программирование, шаблоны, django

В документации сказано, что теги нужно хранить в папках templatetags приложений, но бывают теги, которые нужно использовать во всём проекте. Понятно, что можно раскопипастить всё по приложениям, но это не красиво :( Есть ли правильное решение этой проблемы?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Мы для этих целей используем приложение `utilites`, вы можете назвать его как-нибудь еще. И там уже создавать теги, методы и классы, необходимые для работы другим приложениям.

Копипастить конечно же ничего не надо. Просто в нужных вам местах делаете импорт необходимых модулей.

В шаблонах соответственно `load`.

Comment: Или вообще `common`, раз общие. Вполне себе решение

Comment: Да, можно и `common`. Только неплохо еще быть уверенным, чтобы оно не пересекалось с каким-нибудь встроенным модулем `common` ;).

Answer (score 3):

Зачем же копипастить? Допустим в проекте `projectus` есть приложение `app1` в котором в файле `tags.py` прописан тег/функция/класс `avatar_src` который используется в ругих приложениях. Что мешает делать

```
from projectus.app1.tags import avatar_src
```

в местах где он необходим?